# Semi Colon issue in Apache Derby

Tags: sql, derby

What i want is to store java statement with a semi colon in my embedded derby database. However i am not quite able to generate the simple SQL insert statement that would work. I believe that when the control encounters the semi colon statement in the string if considers it as the termination character and errors are thrown. Try the below:

```
create table dummy(keys int, vals varchar(255));
insert into dummy values (10,'System.out.println();');
```

The above statement fails with errors. However if i remove the semi colon it works

```
insert into dummy values (10,'System.out.println()');
```

Has anyone seen this before if so which escape character did you use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to see what context you are trying to execute the sql statement in, i.e. the surrounding code. If this is in a java program, something like this may work:

```
int n = stmt.executeUpdate("insert into dummy values (10, 'System.out.println()$;') {ESCAPE '$'}");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am just using a sql editor provided by eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Your statements work fine when I run them using Derby's "ij" sql editor:

```
ij version 10.12
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:tt;create=true';
ij> create table dummy(keys int, vals varchar(255));
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
ij> insert into dummy values (10,'System.out.println();');
1 row inserted/updated/deleted
ij> select * from dummy;
KEYS       |VALS

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
10         |System.out.println();


1 row selected
```

Perhaps the problem lies elsewhere. If you could include more details about the exact message you get, that might help.

Comment: Error 1:
insert into droolstest.dummy values (10, 'System.out.println()
VALUES clause must contain at least one element. Empty elements are not allowed. 
Error 2: ');
Syntax error: Encountered "\'" at line 1, column 1.

Comment: BTW i am using eclipse's Eclipse Data Tools Platform pulgin which enable me to execute the queries within ide. May be the problem lies there but i am not too sure.

Comment: It certainly sounds like the problem is in your IDE. It seems like it is looking for semi-colons without considering whether or not those semi-colons are enclosed in quoted strings or not.